# How to use variable in RDLC

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I'm new in C# and I wonder if I can use variables in RDLC ?? If I can use, pls tell me how to use it. What I mean is assign values into variables.. or something like that..

I have purchase and payment table.In my report, i need to draw specific columns from these two tables, for example,

```
  [PurchaseNo]  [PaymentDate]  [PurchaseAmount]   [PaymentAmount]

     c1          12/3/2012       1000               200
                 12/4/2012       1000               500
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
     SubTotal                    1000               700
   --------------------------------------------------------------------

     c2          12/3/2012       900               300
                 12/4/2012       900               500
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
     SubTotal                    900               800
   --------------------------------------------------------------------

     Total                       1900              1500
```

UI is like that.. but when i created RDLC and ran it..

```
  [PurchaseNo]  [PaymentDate]  [PurchaseAmount]   [PaymentAmount]

     c1          12/3/2012       1000               200
                 12/4/2012       1000               500
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
     SubTotal                    2000               700
   --------------------------------------------------------------------

     c2          12/3/2012       900                300
                 12/4/2012       900                500
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
     SubTotal                    1800               800
   --------------------------------------------------------------------

     Total                       3800               1500
```

that's the problem i'm currently having now..
I don't know to add the PurchaseAmount and Payment can't be paid in one day..
so what I think is I'll create a variable in RDLC and in RDLC, I'll use IIf function to check if the PurchaseNo is equal or not. If it's equal, I'll avoid adding PurchaseAmount..
and store in the variable. Or is there any ways pls tell me!

is anyone know , pls help me!!

Comment: For tagging purposes, is this SSRS 2005 or 2008? Parameter are available in both versions.

Comment: The logic for your subtotals isn't clear. If you just want the maximum minimum, or first within your c1, c2 groups as a subtotal, then this is easily done without adding a variable or parameter.

Comment: Sorry that my info aren't clear.. I'm using VS2010 and NHibernate. I've create DataSet in my project and invoke Nhibernate query to get all the values from DataSet. Yep, I've grouped by PurchaseNo and also added group header and footer in my RDLC but sth wrong and I can't figure it out myself !! and PaymentAmount and PaymentDate are the child group of PurchaseNo

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you grouped by `PurchaseAmount` along with `PurchaseNo you could achieve something like this:

```
[PurchaseNo]  [PurchaseAmount] [PaymentDate]   [PaymentAmount]

   c1              $1,000.00     12/3/2012           $200.00
                                 12/4/2012           $500.00
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
   SubTotal        $1,000.00             2           $700.00
 --------------------------------------------------------------------

   c2                $900.00     12/3/2012           $300.00
                                 12/4/2012           $500.00
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
   SubTotal          $900.00             2           $800.00
 --------------------------------------------------------------------

   Total           $1,900.00             4         $1,500.00
```

Comment: I mean without using variables. Instead, you'll be using expressions involving Fields!PurchaseAmount.Value, Sum(Fields!PaymentAmount.Value) and perhaps Count(Fields!PaymentDate.Value).